# Область видимости (класс в классе)

Tags: java, ооп

Есть класс, в конструкторе которого вызывается другой класс, в котором в свою очередь есть публичный геттер, возвращающий значение поля.

```
 public class A { 
      private B b; 
      private A() { 
           b = new B(); 
      } 
      private String method() { 
           b.getField(); // 1 
      } 
 } 
 class B extends JTabbedPane { 
      private String f; 
      public String getField() { 
           return f; 
      } 
 }
```

Проблема в строке 1, метод класса `В.getField` недоступен.

> Error:(146, 37) java: cannot find symbol symbol: method getField() location: variable pCommon of type javax.swing.JTabbedPane

Comment: `private class B;` - что это значит? `Class B`  - почему *Class* с большой буквы?

Comment: Приложение SWING, класс В - это по сути расширенный класс JPanel. С большой буквы  - описка

Comment: Укажите сообщение об ошибке дословно.

Comment: Error:(146, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getField()
  location: variable pCommon of type javax.swing.JTabbedPane

Comment: @Tariel складывается ощущение, что при упрощении примера Вы потеряли существенные детали. Попробуйте привести [пример, который воспроизводит Вашу ошибку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Торопился, наделал много ошибок в коде. Вот правильный:           public class A {    private B b;       private A()  {     b = new B(); }                                                                                          private String method() { b.getField(); // 1 }    }                                                                                                              class B extends JTabbedPane {      private String f;                                                                                          public String getField() { return f; } }

Comment: @Tariel Всё нормально с этим кодом. Не может в нём быть указанной ошибки.

Comment: В том то и дело, что с кодом все норм, а ошибка есть.  Сейчас прошелся отладчиком, пока грешу на следующее: класс А реализован как singleton, JFrame, метод вызывается уже после создания окна и ссылка на класс В обнуляется.  Не понятно, почему

Comment: @Tariel  Попробуйте взять код, который Вы здесь написали и вынести его в отдельный проект. Если ошибка не воспроизводиться, то значит она где-то в другом месте. Пока не воспроизведете ошибку мы помочь не в силах. З.Ы. под вопросом есть ссылка «править» с помощью которой можно внести изменения в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Поле объявляется примерно так:

```
[модификатор] [статик/не статик] тип имя;
```

то есть минимум надо так

```
 private B b;
```

У конструктора должны быть скобки:

```
private A() {
    // smth
}
```

Ну и метод `getField` недоступен потому, что в "конструкторе" объявляется одна переменная `b`, доступная только в его области видимости, а в `method` пытаешься обратиться к методу совсем непонятной переменной `b` нигде даже не объявленной.

Также у метода `method` не указан тип выходного параметра, хотя бы `void` например.

В классе `B` — аналогично с методом.

Как это вообще работает — неизвестно.

Comment: Торопился, наделал много ошибок в коде.  Вот правильный:                    public class A {
    private B b;
    private A() {
       b = new B();
    } 
    private method() {
        b.getField(); // 1
    }
}

class B extends JTabbedPane {
    private String f;
    public String getField() { return f; }
}

Comment: Данный ответ уже неактуален, видимо автор поправил вопрос. Метод method() сейчас реализован верно.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.

Моя вина, в тексте вопроса все написано верно, а в реальном коде, в классе А, вместо объявления переменной

```
private B b;
```

написал ссылку на базовый класс

```
private JTabbedPane b;
```

соответственно новые методы не были доступны.
Всем откликнувшимся спасибо.